# How to fetch Github workflows yaml files using Github Actions API

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I am following this documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-repository-workflows

/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows

My sample output looks like this:

```
{
"total_count": 1,
"workflows": [
   {
     "id": 161335,
     "node_id": "MDg6V29ya2Zsb3cxNjEzMzU=",
     "name": "CI",
     "path": ".github/workflows/blank.yaml",
     "state": "active",
     "created_at": "2020-01-08T23:48:37.000-08:00",
     "updated_at": "2020-01-08T23:50:21.000-08:00",
     "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/workflows/161335",
     "html_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/blob/master/.github/workflows/161335",
     "badge_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/workflows/CI/badge.svg"
   }
 ]
}
```

How do I fetch the workflow yaml file from this output

Comment: An option could be to extract the `path` field from the answer for each workflow, and then split it by `/`(or replacing `.github/workflows/` by `""`) to get the workflow file name. I've done something similar [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-github/blob/master/github/delete/workflow-logs/src/formula/formula.py) in python, line 30.

Comment: Once I get the workflow file name, what is my next step. how will the api link look like

Comment: It depends, what do you want to achieve? For example, to list all this workflow file runs, you could use `https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repository}/actions/workflows/{workflow_file_name}/runs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the filename, use the [Get repository content API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content) to fetch the file.

For your file, that'd be:

```sh
 curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/contents/.github/workflows/blank.yaml
```

The response JSON will contain a field `content`, which contains the encoded contents of that workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Workflow yaml file in plain text:

```
curl \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \  
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octo-org/octo-repo/master/.github/workflows/blank.yaml
```